# Appending a repeated list in python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list here :

`x = [['a', 'b']]`

`y = ['c', 'd', 'e']`

I want to append the list `y` to make `x` in the form

`x = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]`

`x.append(y*3)` makes `x = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e']]`

`x.append([y]*3)` makes `x = [['a', 'b'], [['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]]`

How can I make the list `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]` from `x` and `y`?

Comment: `x.extend([y] * 3)`? — `append` will add exactly *one* additional item to the list. Since you want to add 3, that's the wrong method. `extend` can add multiple elements.

Comment: `x += [y] * 3` or `x.extned([y] * 3)`

Comment: x.extend([y] * 3) and x += [y] * 3 both works. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
x = [['a', 'b']]

y = ['c', 'd', 'e']

x += [y] * 3

print(x)
```

This will output :

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [['a', 'b']]
y = ['c', 'd', 'e']
x=x+[y]+[y]+[y]
print(x)

output:
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```